# java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.executor.cores

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to count the number of cores in each executor with this code:

```
sqlContext.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.executor.cores").toInt
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
spark.executor.cores
java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.executor.cores
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$get$1.apply(SparkConf.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$get$1.apply(SparkConf.scala:193)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

Why is this failing?

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information? Also, do a search for `spark.executor.cores` [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). You'll see that this property is defined only under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

`sqlContext.sparkContext.getConf.getInt("spark.executor.cores", -1)`

Comment: I mean it compiled.

Comment: And ran, presumably, since your original code compiled, just threw a run time error. And it will return -1, since as @Alec said, `spark.executor.cores` isn't always defined. You've not actually fixed anything as you're still not counting the cores